# Easiest way to display a pdf with detailed instructions for users (can be URL)?

Tags: formula, formula-field, pdf, document

I have converted an Excel doc to a pdf I have stored in Google Drive and saved it with permissions so anyone with the link can view. I'd like to make it available in Salesforce on all records of my custom object Performance Reviews so staff know how to rate staff.
Is there a formula in a formula field that does this? Or is it best to save it as a Document and post/link to it somehow? I used to know this, thanks for your help!

Comment: Just want to clarify, is this related to your issue? http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_chatter_files_connect_google_drive.htm

Comment: You could create it as a custom link and throw it on the respective layout. Probably the easiest and most consistent if the URL isn't gonna change much and you just want the link on all the records in the UI.

Comment: @unidha Thanks, but no, it's not related to that, as this is just one document I'd like to post for instructions (and it doesn't have to be in Google Drive, that was just one thought).

Comment: @cricketlang Thanks for your help! This is exactly what I needed. For anyone else viewing this, here's a how to guide to help you accomplish this: https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_web_integration_links.pdf

Comment: @cricketlang why not put this in Answer?

Comment: @cricketlang sorry, I'm new and am used to the Collaboration portal where there's an easy way to mark an answer as best...  I will try to find the way to do so and will definitely promote your answer, thanks for your patience!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so you can mark solved. Wasn't exactly sure what you were wanting so I put it as a comment.

Comment: @cricketlang Thanks! I hope I did that correctly. Thx again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution for putting links on a standard page layout would be with a Custom Link. Create a custom link in the object, add your URL, and then add that link to the desired page layout(s). If the link ever changes, all you'll need to do is change the URL for the link.